# Numerical Differenciation as Matrix-Vector Product

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code to approximate the second derivative of a function `f()` using the formula:

[image]

I would like to compare two different approaches; With loops and with matrix-vector product and hope to show that the `numpy` version is faster:

```
def get_derivative_loop(X):                             
    DDF = []
    for i in range(1,len(X)-1):
         DDF.append((f(X[i-1]) - 2*f(X[i]) + f(X[i+1]))/(h**2))
    return DDF
def get_derivative_matrix(X):
    A = (np.diag(np.ones(m)) + 
         np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) +  
         np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2)
    return np.dot(A[0:m-2], f(X))
```

As expected lot of time is consumed in constructing the matrix `A`. Is there any better solution to construct a three-diagonal Matrix in numpy?

Profiling both functions yields:

```
Total time: 0.003942 s
File: diff.py
Function: get_derivative_matrix at line 17

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    17                                           @profile
    18                                           def get_derivative_matrix(X):
    19         1         3584   3584.0     90.9      A = (np.diag(np.ones(m)) + np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2)
    20         1          358    358.0      9.1      return np.dot(A[0:m-2], f(X))

Total time: 0.004111 s
File: diff.py
Function: get_derivative_loop at line 22

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    22                                           @profile
    23                                           def get_derivative_loop(X):
    24         1            1      1.0      0.0      DDF = []
    25       499          188      0.4      4.6      for i in range(1, len(X)-1):
    26       498         3921      7.9     95.4          DDF.append((f(X[i-1]) - 2*f(X[i]) + f(X[i+1]))/(h**2))
    27                                           
    28         1            1      1.0      0.0      return DDF
    A = (np.diag(np.ones(m)) +
         np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) + 
         np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2)
    return np.dot(A[0:m-2], f(X))
```

**EDIT**

Although it is right, that the initialisation is done only once, so there is no need for optimisation, however I found it interesting to come up with a nice and fast way to setup that matrix.

Here are the profile-results using `Divakar` method

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.006923 s
File: diff.py
Function: get_derivative_matrix_divakar at line 19

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    19                                           @profile
    20                                           def get_derivative_matrix_divakar(X):
    21                                           
    22                                               # Setup output array, equivalent to A
    23         1           48     48.0      0.7      out = np.zeros((m, 3+m-2))
    24                                           
    25                                               # Setup the triplets in each row as [1,-2,1]
    26         1         1485   1485.0     21.5      out[:, 0:3] = 1
    27         1           22     22.0      0.3      out[:, 1] = -2
    28                                           
    29                                               # Slice and perform matrix-multiplication
    30         1         5368   5368.0     77.5      return np.dot(out.ravel()[:m*(m-2)].reshape(m-2, -1)/(h**2), f(X))


Total time: 0.019717 s
File: diff.py
Function: get_derivative_matrix at line 45

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    45                                           @profile
    46                                           def get_derivative_matrix(X):
    47         1        18813  18813.0     95.4      A = (np.diag(np.ones(m)) + np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2)
    48         1          904    904.0      4.6      return np.dot(A[0:m-2], f(X))



Total time: 0.000108 s
File: diff.py
Function: get_derivative_slice at line 41

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    41                                           @profile
    42                                           def get_derivative_slice(X):
    43         1          108    108.0    100.0      return (f(X[0:-2]) - 2*f(X[1:-1]) + f(X[2:]))/(h**2)
```

The new method is faster. However, I don't understand why `21.5%`  is spent on this initialisation     `out[:, 0:3] = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `m = 9`, the three-diagonal matrix without the scaling by `h` would look like this -

```
array([[ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1., -2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

One can see that going row-wise, there are exactly `7` (=m-2) zeros separating two triplets of `[1,-2,1]`. So, as an hack, one can create
a regular 2D array with those replicated triplets as the first three columns, something like this -

```
array([[ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1., -2.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The advantage with the above matrix creation is easy indexing, which must be pretty efficient. So, the leftover work to get us the desired output, would be slicing to restrict us to `m**2` elements and taking care of the triplets at the end.

At the end, we would have something like this to get the three-diagonal matrix -

```
def three_diag_mat(m,h):
    # Initialize output array
    out = np.zeros((m,3+m-2))

    # Setup the triplets in each row as [1,-2,1]
    out[:,:3] = 1
    out[:,1] = -2

    # Reset the ending "1" of the second last row as zero.
    out[m-2,2] = 0

    # Slice upto m**2 elements in a flattened version.
    # Then, scale down the sliced output by h**2 for the final output. 
    return (out.ravel()[:m**2].reshape(m,m))/(h**2)
```

**Runtime tests and verify results**

Case #1:

```
In [8]: m = 100; h = 10

In [9]: %timeit (np.diag(np.ones(m)) + 
np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit three_diag_mat(m,h)
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.8 µs per loop

In [11]: np.array_equal((np.diag(np.ones(m)) + np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) +
 np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2),three_diag_mat(m,h))
Out[11]: True
```

Case #2:

```
In [12]: m = 1000; h = 10

In [13]: %timeit (np.diag(np.ones(m)) + 
np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) + np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.2 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit three_diag_mat(m,h)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.66 ms per loop

In [15]: np.array_equal((np.diag(np.ones(m)) + np.diag(-2*np.ones(m-1), 1) + 
np.diag(np.ones(m-2), 2))/(h**2),three_diag_mat(m,h))
```

---

**Specific use-case:** For the use-case, where you are using `A[0:m-2]`, you can avoid few calculations and have a modified `get_derivative_matrix` like so :

```
def get_derivative_matrix(X):

    # Setup output array, equivalent to A
    out = np.zeros((m,3+m-2))

    # Setup the triplets in each row as [1,-2,1]
    out[:,:3] = 1
    out[:,1] = -2

    # Slice and perform matrix-multiplication
    return np.dot(out.ravel()[:m*(m-2)].reshape(m-2,-1)/(h**2), f(X))
```

Comment: Looks "ugly" :-) but is certainly faster. However, that would make the scalar product at the end useless, right?

Comment: @Tengis That's right! So, you would have something like the one shown in the edited code at the end. Check it out! Let me know the kind of speedups you are getting with it?

Comment: @Tengis Ah that's sort of surprising. To make it more efficient I think, you can do two separate indexing to replace `out[:, 0:3] = 1`: `out[:, 0] = 1; out[:, 2] = 1`, keeping rest of the code the same.

Comment: I tried that before, since I thought that would be less redundant. Unfortunately, did not make the overall function faster. Anyway, I think your solution is the best, and the initialisation should not be part of the profiling, since it is done once.

Comment: `out[:, 2] = 1` eats 22.4%  while the other two assignments 0.4% and 0.1% resp. That is strange, is it not?

Comment: @Tengis I used `timeit` and the results from it make a lot more sense - http://pastebin.com/KngeKn9m

Comment: Yes with `timeit`  it shows reasonable times. Thankx!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to construct the matrix. You can directly use the vector f. e.g. following version will be fine

```
def get_derivative(x,f,h):
    fx=f(x)
return (fx[:-2]-2*fx[1:-1]+fx[2:])/h**2
```

The matrix method will be useful in case of repetitive derivative calculations. You store the matrix and reuse it every time. It becomes more useful for higher order accuracy.

Comment: I don't want to use slicing to solve this, even if it is faster (~100). I just thought there must be a way to construct that matrix without using three times `diag()`

Comment: There might be a faster way to set up the matrix, however in my experience the initialization has never been the bottle neck for my calculations if you set up the matrix only once and not at every function call, so this seems like a premature optimization.